# CSS - how to overwrite using CSS?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I only want to change the colour for the title text, I dont know why the following code does not work?

```
<div class="mytitle">
this is the title in white
</div>

<div class="mytitle alt">
this is the title in red
</div>
<div class="mytitle alt2">
this is the title in black
</div>




.mytitle{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 37px !important;
    line-height: 40px !important;
    display:block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 0 12px;
    padding: 0 15px 5px 0 !important;
    color: white;
    width:500px;
}
.mytitle .alt{
    color: red;
}
.mytitle .alt2{
    color: black;
}
```

EDIT: it would only use "mytitle" tag, it would not use alt or alt2, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces between the class definitions:

```
.mytitle.alt
```

Comment: that was a typo on my side, the actual css has a space.

Comment: 001, *remove* the space. .mytitle .alt (with space) applies to .alt INSIDE .mytitle, whereas .mytitle.alt (without space) applies to elements with both classes.

Comment: Bear in mind IE6 reads .foo.bar as simply .bar - that can be damning if you wanted to reuse the .bar part for other classes than .foo.

Answer (score 1):

simple remove .mytitle

```
.alt{  color: red;}       
.alt2{ color: black;}
```

and you will get all alt/alt2 colored, or

```
.mytitle.alt{ color: red; }       
.mytitle.alt2{ color: black;}
```

for the both together.